# Conversion Stored Procedure from Sybase to HSQL

Tags: sybase, hsqldb

Currently I confront a problem about the converting the stored procedure from Sybase to HSQL automatically, at least I hope it will success. As far as I explore, I have find several difference between 2 of them as follow:

1. Group by, sybase supports the grammar which allows the column name in
   the group by clause different from these in the select clause, which
   is forbidden in hsql.
2. Having clause is the same with group by clause.
3. return statement is only allowed in the hsql function, but is allowed in sybase stored procedure.
4. sybase provides some system procedures which is different from that of hsql.
5. sybase allows 'using with recompile in "create procedure"', but i don't find any option to replace it.
6. ... there are a lot of other differences.

---

So here I wonder is it possible to achieve this conversion automatically? Do you guys has any experience on this problem.

Looking forward your replying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HSQDB allows you to use only some of the columns of GROUP BY in the SELECT list (or in the HAVING clause).

Instead of RETURN, you can assign to an OUT or INOUT parameter of the procedure.

You can ignore 'using with recompile'

Comment: Thank you fredt, it so kind of you.